# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings does not work with an App.config file created programmatically

Tags: c#, xml

I ran into something interesting. I am trying to make a quick console app for our clients to run to change some connection strings on some of their programs. This being a "quick app" for clients, I want it to be "idiot proof".

One of the main things the app does is re-create a default config file should it not find it.

```
 if (!File.Exists("./App.config"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Config file is missing. Creating a new one now..");
            //file doesn't exist, let's create one.
            var doc = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-16", null)
                ,new XElement("configuration"
                    , new XElement("startup"
                        , new XElement("supportedRuntime", new XAttribute("version", "v4.0")
                            , new XAttribute("sku", ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5")))
                , new XElement("appSettings"
                    , new XElement("add", new XAttribute("key", "targetDatabaseName"), new XAttribute("value", ""))
                    , new XElement("add", new XAttribute("key", "applicationServer"), new XAttribute("value", ""))
                    , new XElement("add", new XAttribute("key", "sqlServer"), new XAttribute("value", ""))
                    , new XElement("add", new XAttribute("key", "applicationServerPort"), new XAttribute("value", ""))
                    , new XElement("add", new XAttribute("key", "customSearchPath"), new XAttribute("value", "")))));


            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
                {
                    doc.Save(xw);
                    xw.Close();
                }

                doc.Save("./App.config");
                sw.Close();
                
            }

        }
```

While testing I noticed that if the original App.config file is removed and re-created using the app, all of the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` lines cease to function correctly. They always return null values per each key even if I manually change the values in the re-created config file.

This leads me to think there is some underlying way config files are matched up with their exe files?

### How do I get my application to recognize a dynamically generated app.config file?

*Edit*

I added the code I am using to grab the values from the config file below, as well as the current config file I have that has been created by my app.

```
 _targetDatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["targetDatabaseName"];
        _applicationServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationServer"];
        _sqlServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sqlServer"];
        _applicationServerPort = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationServerPort"];

        var emptyKeys = new List<string>();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_targetDatabaseName))
            emptyKeys.Add("targetDatabaseName");

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_applicationServer))
            emptyKeys.Add("applicationServer");

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_sqlServer))
            emptyKeys.Add("sqlServer");

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_applicationServerPort))
            emptyKeys.Add("applicationServerPort");

        if (emptyKeys.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are missing one of the following required keys "
            + string.Join(",", emptyKeys) +". Press"
                + " a key to exit the application.");

            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
```

Here is the current config file as well with real values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="targetDatabaseName" value="" />
    <add key="applicationServer" value="" />
    <add key="sqlServer" value="" />
    <add key="applicationServerPort" value="" />
    <add key="customSearchPath" value="" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you delete the app.config, run your app (it will save a new app.config), close the app, and open the app again, does it work?  Or, is it only failing on the first run without the app.config?

Comment: No it still continues to return null values for everything. Ill post the code I have that checks for the values. Give me a sec

Comment: Sorry, on a side note... I've done .NET for a while and have never encountered a user deleting the app.config.  Are you sure this is necessary to  'idiot proof' the application?

Comment: I don't have .NET installed locally, else I'd try it.  I think the _Configuration_ node should be _configuration_.  Does that work?

Comment: I appreciate the help anyway jglouie. Not many people take the time out to actually duplicate the problem setup. I did catch that uppercase configuration node and changed it but am still getting null values. I might have to hack it and import the xml file manually using linq since this is required tomorrow morning.

Comment: I've noticed that whenever I build, my App.config gets changed to $assemblyname$.config.  If my project was a console app named Program1, the config gets renamed to Program1.exe.config - it never creates an app.config.  The config manager looks for the assemblyname.config

Comment: That's a good point. I just tried making my app spit out an `Aprima_Client_Connection_App.exe.config` file but still getting the same result

Comment: But does it work properly when the app is relaunched after the file is generated?

Comment: Also, have you tried ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection?  This method will tell the ConfigurationManager to reload the config section from disk?

Comment: Negative, it does not work when relaunching the app. I will try the `RefreshSection` code right now

Comment: Here is a sample from MSDN of the file being altered during runtime:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection(v=vs.110).aspx.  If that works, I will add an answer in the morning with it

Comment: `RefreshSection` did the trick ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2 things will solve your problem.

1. The config file needs to be the name of assembly
2. You need to tell the configuration manager to reload the section you want from the file and not what is in memory:

   ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")

Information on the configuration manager can be found in the MSDN here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: the ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings") is what I was missing, thank you, worked for me now